# Download APK file from Google Play Developer Console programmatically

Tags: android, google-play, apk

I have an Android project in my Google Play Developer Console. I managed to automate uploading of nightly build to the Alpha channel but I also need to download the APK to get its md5 hash for my internal purposes.

I can't get md5 hash before uploading because App Signing by Google Play is enabled for this app so each APK file that I upload is re-signed with Google's keystore.

Is there a way to download APK file from Alpha channel for my own project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download original and re-signed APKs from the Play Console, in the Artifact Library.

There isn't an API to download re-signed APKs today unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Pierre's answer is correct. However, taking an MD5 hash of your APK is probably a mistake. In particular if you use this for verification you will probably introduce a bug. This is because of [Google Play security metadata](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/06/google-play-security-metadata-and.html). This won't be consistent on all versions of your APK, and in particular can change with time without you republishing.

If you need to check the authenticity of your app, can I recommend the primary thing you check is the app signing certificate hash. This should be enough for almost anyone and is what major app developers do. If this is not good enough, please check the hash of any particular section of your app you are worried about (eg the classes.dex or a particular resource file). Please don't check the whole APK, you will cause yourself problems.